# How does regex (0*1*)* denote all binary strings?

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Correction Edit: I want to know how (0*1*)* denotes all binary strings, not (0*1)*.

Just started learning about regex. I was told

```
Language denoted by the regex( (0+1)* )
```

denotes all binary strings.

My understanding is,

```
L(R + S) = L(R) Union L(s)
```

so

```
L(0+1) = L(0) U L(1) = {0, 1}
```

and when you add the * i.e. {0, 1}*, it can be a mix of 0s and 1s in however order (1 can come before the 0), and however many times. That is why it denotes all binary strings.

I was also told

```
L(RS) = L(R)L(S)
```

So `L( (10)* )` is `{1} {0}` concatenated together as many as times as we want. So `L( (10)* ) = {10, 1010, 101010 etc.}` but `01` does not belong in `L( (10)* )` because when concatenating, the order of the symbols cannot change. The order of the symbols can only change if they are separated with a comma in the set (i.e. union, not concatenation).

So how does L( (0*1*)* ) = the set of all binary strings = L( (0+1)* )?

My understanding is,

```
L( (0*1*)* ) 
= ( L(0*)L(1*) )* 
= ( {01, 001, 0001, 011, 0011, 000111 etc.} )*
= {01, 01001, 010001, 01011, 010011, 01000111 etc.}
```

and as seen, there is no way for the symbols to be lead with 1 or end with 0. So how does it equal the set of all binary strings (I just started learning about this, so I'm trying to figure out where my understanding is incorrect).

Comment: Where's the contradiction? Who says that $L((0*1)*)$ (as opposed to $L((0+1)*)$ is the set of all binary strings?

Comment: In the title, you wrote (0*1)* then in the body of the question, you seem to be asking about (0+1)*. Which are you asking about? Also what programming environment are you in?

Comment: Hint: Does (0*1)* detect a string with only zeroes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't.

Your unfolding is not completely correct: `0*` generates *zero or more* zeroes, so `0*1` generates the strings `1`, `01`, `001` and so forth.

However `(0*1)*` still doesn't generate all binary strings: It cannot generate any string that *ends with* `0`.

Comment: Turns out an error was made. It is now mentioned in my course that (0+1)* ≡ (0*1*)* (set of all binary strings). I still don't understand how (I edited my post to show my steps of trying to figure out how. Would you be able to re-answer? Thanks in advance).

Comment: Henning's first comment still applies. The fact is, the Klee Star allows for empty strings too, i.e. zero copies of whatever is in the brackets. If you want, for example, the string `10`, you write it as a concatenation of `1` and `0`. Both of these are accepted by `0*1*`, as the first one is the concatenation of the empty string (in `0*`) with `1`, and similarly for the other one.

Answer (score 2):

That regex does capture all binary strings:
It does this because the group is prefaced by a 0 or more *, which allows for any combinations of the internal matches to be part of the overall match.  I'll try to break it out below.

**$0$* = $0$ or more "$0$"s**

Matches: $00 | 000 | 0$

**$1$* = $0$ or more "$1$"s**

Matches: $11 | 111 | 1$

**$(0*1*)$ = $0$ or more $0$s then any number of $1$s** (This is the match you were thinking of.)

Matches: $1 | 01 | 0111 | 000001$

**$(0*1*)$* = $0$ or more matches for $0$ then zero or more matches for $1$s. Then if there are any more $0$s or $1$s continue.**
Matches: All strings containing $0$s and $1$s.

**Break out this string for example:**

$10001010111$

$1=$ No matches on $0$ (`0*`1*)* $1$ Match on $1$ (0*`1`**)* moves to the last * (0*1*)`*` (Are there more?)

$0001=$ $3$ matches on $0$ (`0*`1*)* $1$ Match on $1$ (0*`1*`)* moves to the last * (0*1*)`*`

$01=$ $1$ match on $0$ (`0*`1*)* $1$ Match on $1$ (0*`1*`)* moves to the last * (0*1*)`*`

$0111=$ $1$ match on $0$ (`0*`1*)* $3$ Matches on $1$ (0*`1*`)* moves to the last * (0*1*)`*`(No more)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format both, your questions and your answers :)

Comment: 0* means zero or more occurrence of 0. That means there are possibilities for {e} simply says no occurrence. Please consider this too. 
For an example x* = { e, x, xx, xxx, xxxx, … }
So, 0* = {e,0,00,000, ... }

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the strings consisting of one or more zeros only and the strings consisting of one or more ones only are also in $L(0^*)L(1^*)$  because both $L(0^*)$ and $L(1^*)$ contain the empty string. So $0, 1\in (L(0^*)L(1^*))$ which means that $\{0, 1\}^*\subseteq (L(0^*)L(1^*))^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R:= (0^*1^*)^*$. We have to show that $R \equiv(0+1)^*$. We will do so by showing that every string $w\in \{0,1\}^*$ belongs to $L(R)$ by induction on the length of $w$.

Evidently, $\varepsilon\in L(R)$. Now, fix $k\geqslant 0$ and suppose that for all strings $u\in\{0,1\}^*$,
$|u| = k \implies u \in L(R)$. Let $w\in\{0,1\}^*$ be such that $|w| = k+1$. Then, either $w = 0x$ or $w = 1x$ for some $x \in \{0,1\}^*$ with $|x| = k $. By induction hypothesis, $x \in L(R)$. Now, observe that $$R=(0^*1^*)^* \equiv \varepsilon +0^*1^*(0^*1^*)^* = \varepsilon +0^*1^*R\geqslant 0R + 1R.$$ It immediately follows that $w\in L(R)$. This finishes the proof. $\square$